# Undefined index error - Defined index after the variable is called

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code snippet(s):

```
<div class="message_display_here">
    <?php
    // check if file is empty
    if ($_FILES['attachment']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['attachment']['error'] == 0) {
        // no file attached, so do nothing
    } else {
        echo "                
                        <form action='inc/download_attachment.php' method='post'>
                            <button type='submit' name='save'> Download</button>
                        </form>";
    }
    ?>
</div>

<div id="write_message_area">
    <?php
    if ($user == "") {
        // display nothing
    } else {
        echo "<input id='file-input name='attachment' type='file' style='margin-left:15px;'/>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

As you can input type file `attachment` is defined after this:

```
if ($_FILES['attachment']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['attachment']['error'] == 0){
```

But cannot move the content in the `write_message_area` above the above line of code, since they are two separate divs, and it will effect the CSS.

Just to clarify, I am getting an undefined index error on this line:

```
if ($_FILES['attachment']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['attachment']['error'] == 0){
```

I know why I am getting the error, but just don't know how I can fix it without moving the content from one div to another, which I do not want to do.

### Edit

**Why I have two forms**:

**Form 1** (in `write_message_area`):

Form 1 is required for a user to send a message to another user.

```
<?php
echo " 
    <form action='messages.php?u=$user' method='post'>
        <textarea name='msg_body' rows='3' maxlength='255' cols='110' placeholder='Send message...'></textarea> 
        <input type='submit' name='send' value='Send'/> 
        <input id='file-input' name='attachment' type='file' style='margin-left:15px;'/>
    </form>";                       
?>
```

**Form 2** (is in `message_displayed_here`):

```
<form action='inc/download_attachment.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <button type='submit' name='save'> Download</button>
</form>";
```

So a user uses form 1 to type their message and add an attachment (if they want). If the user HAS uploaded an attachment, then form 2 will be displayed within the div for each single_message post. Form 2 is a button which allows the user to on click, save the sent attachment on their local disk.

Comment: You need to check for `$_FILES['attachment']`, not for `$_FILES['attachment']['size']`. Also, use `if( isset($_FILES['attachment']) )`. When you load the page, before submitting form, `$_FILES` has no index(es).  But - in fact - you have to remove the condition in that form, because your form is displayed only if a file is submitted, but if the form is not displayed, how you can submit file? Unless than submission form is in another page.

Comment: @fusion3k Yeah that too and was the first thing that popped into my head before I submitted my answer. I'll add that, however I have a bit of trouble wrapping my head around what he wants to do here.

Comment: Freddy, I posted an answer below but TBH, have a hard time to figure out what you're trying to do here. Plus, you also have a missing quote for `id='file-input`. Read what I wrote and take it from there. If you've any problems, I'll try and help the best I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have no valid enctype in your form to handle files, so add it; it's required.

```
<form action='inc/download_attachment.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Plus, and to be honest; I don't know what you're trying to do with the input being outside the form tags. The input needs to be part of the form.

You might want to move your `</form>` tag to be after the input.

Also, you've a missing quote here `<input id='file-input` <<<
that should read as `<input id='file-input'`

---

Quoting from comments:

> *"You need to check for $_FILES['attachment'], not for $_FILES['attachment']['size']. Also, use if( isset($_FILES['attachment']) ). When you load the page, before submitting form, $_FILES has no index(es)."*
>
> *"But - in fact - you have to remove the condition in that form, because your form is displayed only if a file is submitted, but if the form is not displayed, how you can submit file? Unless than submission form is in another page. – fusion3k"*

---

**Edit:** After looking at your conditional statement a bit closer.

Your logic is off.

`['error'] == 0` means *Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success.* as per the manual

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

So get rid of that and check for emptyness, along with what I already stated in my original answer.

```
if (

    !empty($_FILES['attachment']) 
    && $_FILES['attachment']['size'] == 0 


) {

// do something

}
```

Or, change `['error'] == 0)` to `['error'] != 0)` using the `!` negation operator.

Then check for error level. Consult the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: @fusion3k :-) Now, still no word from the OP. He might be testing and/or debugging. I on the other hand am getting hungry, so I think I'll take a slight break and have a quick bite to eat. *ciao!*

Comment: _Bon Appétit!_ See you around

Comment: @Fred-ii- - Apologies for the delayed response. I myself took a break from coding, but I am back now. Also, finally learnt what OP means thanks to your last comment! I will read you answer now, and will update you if any questions arise :)

Comment: @fusion3k Thanks, enjoyed it. Plus, I noticed another flaw in their logic, being `if...['error'] == 0)` and made an edit about it. Still no work from the OP. Had I known, I wouldn't have posted an answer and should have simply said that in a comment that they didn't have a valid enctype and having him take it from there. I am done here. The OP can take it from here. Have a great day/evening (*wherever you may be*) ;-)

Comment: @Freddy Oh there you are *lol*. Well, I've made a few edits so you'll need to reload my answer. That's the best I can do for you. Check for errors with error reporting also. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Good luck, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see you were confused on the what I was trying to achieve with my forms. I have edited my question to provide some clarification :).

Comment: @Freddy Your `<form action='messages.php?u=$user' method='post'>` also needs to contain the enctype.

Comment: @Freddy also, I would add the complete form inside the `<div id="write_message_area">` div area  (with the enctype) where you only have the input. That will work. That's why it's failing along with my other comment. If someone decides to upload a file in the first one and you've no enctype for it, it will fail.

Comment: @Freddy That's great Freddy and you're most welcome, *cheers!*